# How to perform ATTACH DATABASE with PHP SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite

I am using PHP (version 5.3.13) with sqlite3 (version 0.7-dev) enabled.  I want to be able to use the SQLITE3 ability to ATTACH DATABASE so that I can perform JOINed queries, but every time I do ATTACH DATABASE it fails.

```
$dbmain = new SQLite3('main.s3db');
$results = $dbmain->exec("ATTACH DATABASE support.s3db AS ckj");
var_dump($results);
```

The var_dump always shows false, and I'm never able to query on ckj.

Comment: Don't you get some sort of error, say `Error: no such column: support.s3db`?  Try single-quoting filename.  And this is still just a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide the full path quoted.

```
$myroot = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$dbmain = new SQLite3('main.s3db');
$cmd = "ATTACH DATABASE '".$myroot."/support.s3db' AS ckj";
$results = $dbmain->exec($cmd);
var_dump($results);
```

will work correctly.